# Add specific url from a webpage to listbox

Tags: html, vb.net, string, url, replace

Hi there all I'm trying to grab specific links from a website and adding them to a listbox.

Im having two problems:

1. When trying to add the url to the listbox it will be adding the entire html line and not just the url. How can i just add the url?
2. There is nothing showing in the listbox. According to the below code it should be working. And adding the urls to the listbox.

Here is the code im using to grab the links:

```
       Dim theElementCollection As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("DIV")
    For Each curElement As HtmlElement In theElementCollection
        If curElement.OuterHtml.Contains("active_scanner") Then
            If curElement.OuterHtml.Contains("http://scanner.chad.com/SweScanner/") Then
                Dim data As String = curElement.OuterHtml
                data = data.Substring(data.IndexOf("http://scanner.chad.com/SweScanner/"))
                If Not ListBox1.Items.Contains(data) Then ListBox1.Items.Add(data)
                Label4.Text = "Added 1 URL."
            End If
        Else

        End If
```

And here is the website source:

```
<div class="content">
<div class="content-header"><span class="script">Active</span> Scanner</div>
<div class="section" id="active_scanner">
    <ul>
                <li><a href="http://scanner.chad.com/SweScanner/testing-vb">This url will be grabbed</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://scanner.chad.com/SweScanner/testing-vb1">This url will be grabbed</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://scanner.chad.com/SweScanner/testing-vb2">This url will be grabbed</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://scanner.chad.com/SweScanner/testing-vb3-">This url will be grabbed </a></li>
                <li><a href="http://scanner.chad.com/SweScanner/testing-vb4">This url will be grabbed</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://scanner.chad.com/SweScanner/testing-vb5">This url will be grabbed</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://scanner.chad.com/SweScanner/testing-vb6">This url will be grabbed</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://scanner.chad.com/SweScanner/testing-vb7">This url will be grabbed</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://scanner.chad.com/SweScanner/testing-vb8">This url will be grabbed</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://scanner.chad.com/SweScanner/testing-vb9">This url will be grabbed</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://scanner.chad.com/SweScanner/testing-vb10">This url will be grabbed</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://scanner.chad.com/SweScanner/testing-vb11">This url will be grabbed</a></li>
            </ul>
</div>
```

Please can you help me out here.
Thanks
Chad

Comment: you trying to fill your _listBox_ only with this `http://scanner.chad.com/SweScanner/testing-vb` right ??

Comment: Yes just that, but those are just the test urls. Only the http://scanner.chad.com/SweScanner/ will always be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    For Each Link As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.Links()
        i += 1
        If Link.OuterHtml.Contains("scanner.chad.com/SweScanner/testing") Then
            ListBox1.Items.Add(i & ". " & Link.InnerHtml & ": " & Link.OuterHtml)
            Debug.Print(i - 1 & " " & Link.OuterHtml)
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: It did add items to the listbox, but not just the urls. It grabbed every reference of scanner.chad.com. It has to be in the div: id="active_scanner">

Comment: Thanks for quick responses. But same thing, its also grabbing < IMG